# UITableViewCell right detailTextLabel frame resizes after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a UITableView with one Right Detail cell and scrolling disabled and the height of the table set to 44 (same as the cell). The cell displays data representing an object of class A. when the user taps the cell, it pushes a new VC with a table to pick a new object of class A. however when I pop back to the old VC and call `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear`, the `detailTextLabel.frame` is completely changed and not visible.

So in this log, the first line is the initial call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (object 1), and everything displays correctly. The second line is after selecting object 2 (empty string for `detailTextLabel`). The third line is after selecting object 1 again, and the `detailTextLabel` that was working before, now is invisible.

```
2015-03-28 10:48:11.747 dojo[32523:5852510] detail text label: <UITableViewLabel: 0x15d5de470; frame = (463 12; 42 20); text = '1234'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17429a810>>
2015-03-28 10:48:20.374 dojo[32523:5852510] detail text label: <UITableViewLabel: 0x15d5de470; frame = (468.5 13; 36.5 19.5); text = ''; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17429a810>>
2015-03-28 10:48:23.192 dojo[32523:5852510] detail text label: <UITableViewLabel: 0x15d5de470; frame = (505 13; 0 0); text = '1234'; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17429a810>>
```

I have set up the table in a storyboard with the proper reuse id and am calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to get the cell;

Update: [gist for VC](https://gist.github.com/doman412/aa941ed3bb8a3403eaa1)

Update 2: I can't upload my whole project but I've created a [demo project](https://github.com/doman412/UITableViewBugDemo) with a portion of the real code (slightly modified for dependencies) that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: You should post all the code for the controller with the table view. As an aside, If you only have one cell, why are you using a table view at all?

Comment: I am using a table with one cell because i have a separate table above it for other objects and i want the UX to be the same for the user, i.e. tap to edit object.

Comment: May be you should create you custom cell with constraints for labels.

Comment: Or you can override - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and call sizeToFit for label

Comment: @MishaVyrko, I was hoping to avoid that because, this should just work. I get that setting the label's text will resize it but I'm confounded as to why when I set a string, its resized to where its not visible. But yeah, the workaround is to duplicate the cell myself.

Comment: The detail text label will have zero size (I think) if there is no text in it. If you log vehicle.number in the cellForVehicleTableAtIndexPath: method after you pop back, what does it show?

Comment: Can you set up constraints in storyboard for detailTextLabel?

Comment: @rdelmar, in the third line of the log, you can see that the label's frame has a zeroed size and text equal to the first line, it should look identical, i think.

Comment: @MishaVyrko, using `willDisplayCell` and calling `sizeToFit` makes the label visible but it puts it over the Disclosure Indicator Accessory

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed that in your logs. I have no idea why this is happening then. There's no reason that label should disappear if it has text to display. If you can post the whole project somewhere, I could take a look at it, but otherwise, I'm out of ideas. You could fix it by creating your own custom cell, and adding labels with proper constraints, but I don't see why the default cell doesn't work.

Comment: Can you upload your project to github?

Comment: i've uploaded a demo of the project with real code from my project that still exhibits the problem. I can't upload my actual project however. (link in post)

Comment: What actions do you need to take with the demo project to see the problem? You don't even have a cell with right detail in this project.

Comment: in the toolbar, in the details pane, the button 'open modal', its how its opened in the real project

Comment: @rdelmar, my mistake, the push didnt include the files, it does now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, this seems to be a bug in Apple's code. If I use sizeToFit after setting the text (and there is a vehicle.number to see), the number appears, but the chevron disappears until you push then pop back again; this is definitely not the way it should work. You can get around it easily enough by passing a single space as the text when there is no vehicle.number instead of an empty string. So,

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setText: vehicle.number ? : @" "];
```

instead of this,

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setText: vehicle.number ? : @""];
```

The numbers in the log are still behind; that is you need to push and pop again before you see the correct frames in the logs, but the label and the chevron both show up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this will work as a simple workaround. I also noticed before, when the label has disappeared, if I pressed the row but didn't release and the row highlighted, that the label returns.

Comment: @doman412, yeah, it appears that something is not laying out at the correct time. I also noticed that I could fix it by calling layoutSubviews on the cell (but you're not supposed to call that method directly, and layoutIfNeeded didn't work).